# Power BI method to Slice string based on "contains text"

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, slicers

I have a string of concatenated data separated by a delimiter "; ". For example: `Dog; Cat; Mouse;`. (the components of the string can appear in any order leading to a large amount of possibilities)

I am trying to figure out if a custom visual or a method to query the data exists so that if I'm interested in all records that contain "Dog" I can visualize just those....

My first idea was to split the concatenated column in Query editor into 3 separate columns. Then, create a relationship between a table of distinct animals and each of the 3 columns. However, only one active relationship can exists between the distinct animals and the split columns so that's where I stopped.

If this were an excel dashboard I'd just build a VBA drop down box that sliced my data.... so I'm hoping a similar visual slicer exists somewhere....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in the Query Editor, after your Split, I would select all the other columns and from the Transform ribbon choose Unpivot Other Columns.  This will give you 3 rows for each input row, with each animal name on a separate row.

After renaming the generated Attribute and Value columns, you can create the relationship.

Comment: Thanks for all your help on these Mike, I'll get the hang of all this unpivoting/pivoting eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calc column with the FIND function.